# Using numpy to simulate 1000 gas mixtures containing three components

Tags: python, numpy, simulate

I want to generate 1000 gas mixtures with three components that have a defined range. The sum of each mix should be 100. I can't figure out how to relate the components using a for loop.

```
import numpy as np

comp_list = []

c1 = np.arange(80,100, 0.001)

c2 = np.arange(0,14,0.001)

c3 = np.arange(0,4, 0.001)

for i in range(10000):
    comp_sum = c1[i] + c2[i] +c3[i]
    if comp_sum == 100:
        comp_list.append(c1[i], c2[i],c3[i])

print comp_list
```

Comment: I suggest restructuring: first generate `c1`, then for each element of `c1` you can generate `c2` in the remaining concentration range, and then `c3=100-c1-c2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AndrasDeak suggested in comment, you can simply do a `c3 = 100 - c1 - c2` to ensure *SOME* result samples can fulfill your contraints, and then just take up to 1000 samples from the result, one way to do it:

```
# I created more than 1000 samples so that I have enough to slice with
In [35]: c1 = np.random.uniform(80, 100, 10000)

In [36]: c2 = np.random.uniform(0, 14, 10000)

In [37]: c3 = 100 - c1 - c2

In [38]: c3
Out[38]: 
array([ 12.68861952,   4.34446942,  -9.74132792, ...,   3.65083356,
        -0.71305583,   9.78624485])

In [39]: masked = np.where((c3 >= 0) & (c3 <= 4))

# only take up to 1000 samples
In [40]: c1 = c1[masked][:1000]

In [41]: c2 = c2[masked][:1000]

In [42]: c3 = c3[masked][:1000]

# sum of the arrays show 100 in all
In [43]: c1 + c2 + c3
Out[43]: 
array([ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
```

This surely is not be the most efficient way but for simple use case it can achieve what you want.

Comment: I've decided to do the c1 by balance : c1 = 100-c2-c3-nc4-ic4-nc5-ic5-neoc5-n2. However, I only require the data set when c1 is > 80. I've tried: for i in c1_ser:
    if i >=80: export to df but it doesn't seem to be working. I still get values for c1 <80. any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @Joey, first of all glad it helps. Re your issue with c1>80, how you construct your masking? ie. `masked = np.where((c1 >= 80) & (contraints) & ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a direct method by using list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

c1=np.linspace(80,100,100)

carr=np.array([[c1[i],cc2,100-c1[i]-cc2] for i in range(len(c1)) for cc2 in np.arange(0,min(14,100-c1[i]),1)])
```

You can restore your concentration vectors with

```
c1=carr[:,0]
c2=carr[:,1]
c3=carr[:,2]
```

Proof:

```
In [496]: carr.shape
Out[496]: (944, 3)

In [497]: carr.sum(1)

Out[497]: array([ 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
        ...
```

You have to give a little thought to your choice of parameters to get roughly 1000 samples, since for each `c1` you will have a different amount of `c2`. However, this will produce a roughly uniform set of concentrations, you probably just have to be careful around the `c=100` cases (I wasn't).